# How to get "Facebook Like" to focus on items in the page not the page itself?

Tags: facebook, facebook-like

```
<iframe src='http://www.facebook.com/plugins/like.php?href=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.example.com&amp;layout=standard&amp;show_faces=false&amp;width=100&amp;action=like&amp;colorscheme=light&amp;height=35' scrolling='no' frameborder='0' style='border:none; overflow:hidden; width:100px; height:35px;' allowTransparency='true'></iframe>
```

or:

```
<script src='http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1'></script><fb:like href='http://www.example.com' show_faces='false' width='100'></fb:like>
```

I have media files that are loaded dynamically onto a page.

After the file is loaded, I want to put out a Facebook Like button for it so that the text that appears in the Facebook News Feed is specific to the media item.

At the moment it always describes the page itself.

In the developer docs it says to do this you need to set [Open Graph](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like) info in the page HEAD section.

I don't see how that would work with the multiple media items I'm dealing with.

Answer (score 2):

Create a new page for each media item (as a parameter to a script) so that FB indexes each individually:

```
<fb:like href='http://www.example.com/fblike.php?item=name_id_url_whatever' show_faces='false' width='100'></fb:like>
```

Where fblike.php redirects back to the main example.com or whatever page the media item in question is on. You'll probably need some sort of database to track it, unless everything links back to the main page.

Comment: That's an interesting suggestion.  Does facebook allow us to "like" a page that does a redirect (e.g. HTTP Redirect)?

Comment: I dont think that header redirect will work (php `header("Location:some_url")`), but meta refresh works (`<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;some_url" />`).